# Argument of type not assignable to

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this piece of code which gives me an error with typescript.

```
firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('arenas').get()
    .then((snapshot: any) => {
        snapshot.forEach((element: any) => {
            scraptIt(firebaseFunctions.config().sports.url + element.data().url, {
                sports: {
                    listItem: '.LSport',
                    data: ['b']
                }
            }).then((data: any) => {
                sportsArray.push(data)
                sportsArray = [...new Set(data)]
            }).catch((err: any) => { res.send(err); console.log(err) })
        })
    }).catch((err: any) => { res.send(err); console.log(err) })
```

I'm receiving the following error

> Argument of type '{ sports: { listItem: string; data: string[]; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ScrapeOptions'. Property 'sports' is incompatible with index signature. Type '{ listItem: string; data: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | ScrapeOptionList | ScrapeOptionElement'. Type '{ listItem: string; data: string[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'ScrapeOptionElement'.

I'm using this package: [Scrape-It](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/scrape-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the below method signature from Scrapeit library

`declare function scrapeIt<T>(url: string | object, opts:scrapeIt.ScrapeOptions): Promise<T>;`

which means the second parameter for the method `scraptIt()` should be of type `ScrapeOptions`. If you observe the definition of the interface `ScrapeOptions` carefully you can see that it accepts the below format as input

```
export interface ScrapeOptions {
        [key: string]: string | ScrapeOptionList | ScrapeOptionElement;
}
```

The `ScrapeOptionList` interface is defined as

```
export interface ScrapeOptionList {
        listItem: string;
        data: ScrapeOptions;
}
```

In your code you are passing the second parameter as below

```
scraptIt(firebaseFunctions.config().sports.url + element.data().url, {
                sports: {
                    listItem: '.LSport',
                    data: ['b'] // here is the issue
                }
            })
```

the value for `data` should be of type `ScrapeOptions` as per the definition . Hence you need to change it to either a simple string or type of `ScrapeOptionList` or type of `ScrapeOptionElement`.

you can try to change it to `data: 'b'` as per your need
Or set `data`property value as type of `ScrapeOptionList` or `ScrapeOptionElement`.

a sample format to be used should look like below -- (Not sure why are you using `data:['b']`) . In my opinion it should be `data : { "somekey" : 'b'}`

```
pages: {
        listItem: "li.page"
      , name: "pages"
      , data: {
            title: "a"
          , url: {
                selector: "a"
              , attr: "href"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah okay I'll have a look at it. It just strange because I've got the exact same code in two different projects and VS code editors, it's just the one is giving issues and the other one is working. I think it might be the TS Config or something so will also investigate that.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and it's still giving me the same issue for some reason.

Comment: @DivanvanBiljon then it might be a local tsconfig issue for you .. as per the documentation the above implementation seems correct.

Comment: @DivanvanBiljon updated my answer with a sample format ... why are you using `data:['b']` for?data should be an object with a key value pair inside.

Comment: @Nilandri You were right, the selectors I used were not correct.